# if isAjax not working or not detecting ajax request in template

Tags: ajax

I can't stand this and have to ask for help again.. Still working on my buddy's website.

I want to increase a entry's counter (using Entry Count plugin)
So for my _entry.html I added an if statement to see if the request is for Ajax or not. If not, show the entire page. If it is only run the counter twig line.

_entry.html

```
{% if not craft.request.isAjax and not craft.request.isLivePreview %}
    {% extends "_layout" %}
    {% set title = entry.title|t %}

{% block content %}
 {# CONTENT GOES HERE #}
{% endblock %}

{% else %}
    {# ONLY INCREASE THE VIEWS/COUNT #}
    {% do craft.entryCount.increment(entry.id) %}
{% endif %}
```

Javascript on main page

```
$.get($(this).attr('data-url-item'), function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

Now I don't need to actually pickup any data or show it, so I'm using $.get() currently have the console.log() there so I can see which version of the page I'm getting.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also, how this currently works is that the direct url works fine. the $.get() gets the same page (entire HTML/resources) instead of the nothing it should get back (but do activate that twig upon load.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bumping into a Twig gotcha: you can't conditionally extend a template. Either a template extends another template (i.e. it has an `{% extends %}` tag in it) or it doesn't. It doesn't matter if the `{% extends %}` statement is inside an `{% if %}` statement.

The solution is to create an additional layout template – e.g. `_ajax.html` – and use a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to have your entry template extend *one or the other*, before putting the conditional that loads either the content or the call to `entryCount.increment` inside the `{% block content %}`. Note that for your purposes, the `_ajax.html` template can be completely blank, except of course for the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`). Also note that since we now need to test if the request is an Ajax request twice, it makes sense to cache the test to a variable `isAjax`:

```
{% set isAjax = craft.request.isAjax and not craft.request.isLivePreview %}
{% extends not isAjax ? '_layout' : '_ajax' %}
{% block content %}
    {% if not isAjax %}
        {# CONTENT GOES HERE #}
    {% else %}
        {% do craft.entryCount.increment(entry.id) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Not very elegant, is it? A better option might be to create a different endpoint for incrementing the counter entirely, negating the need to create an additional layout template and to wrap most of your content in a conditional. To create a dedicated endpoint for incrementing the counter, you can create [a dynamic route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes). Make sure the route contains a `<number>` token, which will hold your entry ID (the route could just be `count/<number>`, for instance). Have the route point to a new template called `_count.html` or the like, and put the following in that template:

```
{% do craft.entryCount.increment(number) %}
```

You'll have to expose the current entry's ID to your JavaScript somehow, but that's easily done by setting a data attribute somewhere in your markup – e.g.

```
<body data-entryid="{{ entry.id }}">
```

Then, you just need to use jQuery or the like to issue a request to http://yourwebsite.com/count:

```
$.ajax('/count/'+$('body').data('entryid'));
```

Closing thought: So long as you "don't need to actually pickup any data or show it", I'm curious why you couldn't just request the basic template as-is. As long as the template contains the call to `entryCount.increment` somewhere inside the `{% block content %}` block, does it really matter if it loads the full layout behind the scenes? Sure, there's a little overhead, but it's way less work and probably doesn't matter that much in the scheme of things.

Comment: First off, thank you for your suggested solution, I'll dig my face into it in a sec.

I figured it would just be more efficient if it did not load any unnecessary data just to register a view (to explain why. I open a modal with the item's info, instead of loading a new page. But also leave the possibility to share and therefor end up on a single page view of the item.) 

And currently the opening animation lags as the page is loaded through the $.get() I'm pretty sure it wont do this if it does not get an entire page as a respons.

Comment: Whatever happens serverside shouldn't affect the performance of your front end code and as long as you don't add any callbacks (i.e. `success`, `error`, `complete` etc), the `$.ajax` call won't hog any client side resources at all – in other words, yes, if you only call the `do` statement you will use (marginally) less resources serverside, but it won't have any impact on your animation performance whatsoever.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not sure if `$.get` allows not having a `success` callback, but `$.ajax` definitely does.

Comment: I'm not expert on that. But if I console.log(data); i see the entire raw HTML. doesn't that load a lot slower than just a little message (from the increase count bit)? I tried with $.ajax too (first attempt.)

What I can say is that it does take a moment to load, I'd rather it would just increase the count through a request alone. Using the $.get() right?

Comment: Right, but that `console.log` could very well be the reason for the lag by itself :) Just remove the callback entirely. You're not going to use the returned data either way, so you don't need a callback.

Comment: Got it. I'll try your solution and report back soon. Thanks again Mats!

Comment: Thanks again Mats. Went with the Route setup. Clean way of doing what I wanted.

Comment: @Kitsune Awesome, happy it worked out!